# Is it bad to parse the data for white spaces, tabs and other non-printable characters before passing it for indexing to Solr master?

Tags: parsing, solr

I am talking about the custom parsing phase happening in some program not related to Solr and even before the Solr tokenizers can work on it. If I parse the data for say white spaces, tabs and other non printable characters then when that data actually comes to Solr master for indexing, how would the Solr tokenizers differentiate between separate words which were previously separated by spaces or tabs or some other non-printable characters?

Example code and output from pre-processor:

```
<?php$text = '<div>This is a sample text to be indexed</div>';
//Remove HTML tags
$text_refined1 = strip_tags($text);
//Remove non-printable unicode characters
$text_refined2 = preg_replace('/[\x00-\x08\x0B\x0C\x0E-\x1F\x80-\x9F]/u',    '', $text_refined1);
//Remove line feeds, carriage returns and tabs
$text_refined3 = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $text_refined2);
echo $text_refined3;
```

---output---

Thisisasampletexttobeindexed

Comment: It depends on what the output of your pre-processor looks like. Could you provide a sample?

Comment: @TokeEskildsen Thanks for your reply. I have added example code in php and output from pre-processor.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the example you give. e.g. output Thisisasampletexttobeindexed, Solr's existing query analyzer will not be able to tokenize it correctly.

Solr(Lucene) needs some way to seperate the individual words from the input.

You can use solr's analysis admin UI to test this string with different analyzers. In my solr test instance, they all return the original string.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure which Tokenizer to use in Solr. There is a list at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Tokenizers

Indexing a stream of non-delimited English words properly is not supported by any existing Tokenizer in Solr. You could conceivably build a custom one with a dictionary, but it would produce errors as the input is ambiguous. Or you could use the N-Gram Tokenizer and accept a lot of false positives when you search.

The right solution is not to feed such a stream in the first place. If you need the tightly concatenated string for something internal, then produce a separate version for indexing, where you replace the offending characters with space instead of the empty string.